# XYPieChart won't display slice label with iOS 6.x

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to run this in iOS 6.x:

```
NSArray *n = [data allKeys];

long sc = [n count];

XYPieChart *pie = [[XYPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.pieStart, 160, 220)];
[pie setDataSource:self];
[pie setDelegate:self];
[pie setStartPieAngle:M_PI_2];
[pie setAnimationSpeed:1.0];
[pie setLabelFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:11]];
[pie setLabelRadius:40];
[pie setShowPercentage:YES];
[pie setPieBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1]];
[pie setPieCenter:CGPointMake(80, 100)];
[pie setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[pie setLabelShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
pie.tag = tag;

UILabel *t = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 2, 320, 21)];
t.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[t setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:17]];
t.text = title;

UILabel *p = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(71, 90, 18, 18)];
p.text = @"%";
p.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
p.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[p setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13]];
p.layer.cornerRadius = 9;
p.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

int vc = 35;
int lc = 31;

[pie addSubview:t];
[pie addSubview:p];

[self.myScroll addSubview:pie];

self.pieStart += 220;

[pie reloadData];

for(int i = 0; i < sc; i++){

    UIView *cc = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(162, vc, 9, 9)];
    cc.backgroundColor = [self.sliceColors objectAtIndex:(i % self.sliceColors.count)];
    [pie addSubview:cc];

    UILabel *tl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, lc, 134, 17)];
    [tl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10]];
    tl.text = [self.ss objectAtIndex:i];
    [pie addSubview:tl];

    vc += 12;
    lc += 12;

}

//NSLog(@"got here");

UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, pie.frame.size.height - 20, 320, 1)];
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

[pie addSubview:line];
```

What happens is I get the correct sizes for slices and they are shown on the screen but the percentages are not. (It works fine in iOS 7.1).

When I set `[pie setShowPercentage:YES];` to `[pie setShowPercentage:NO];`

and use:`-(NSString *)pieChart:(XYPieChart *)pieChart textForSliceAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return @"test";
}`

Again I don't see anything in iOS 6.x but I see the word "test" in all the big slices.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: I am also facing problm

Comment: @Tommy Unfortunately I did not:(